# c# two excel workbook projects setup giving same data in excel workbook

Tags: c#, excel

I have have created two excel workbook projects in c#.net which call web api and get data process it and fill the excel file and those running well in visual studio. But when I publish them and install one by one then for first project it works well got correct data now I install second project setup that time it is also working well get correct data. Now I rerun first project it fill excel with second project excel data which is wrong data. What goes wrong I don't understand anybody knows this issue.

If you want more details then let me know.

I have created two excel workbook setup and both output file having same data. if I observe then it is taking recent installed application for any other application. so that this is issue.

Application details as following:
1. A form with date time field and one button on trigger of that one web api get called for getting data and as soon as data got excel get filled with that.

I am facing problem only with installed application which internally run recently installed application that need to be resolved. One thing i observed in control panel for installed date for that recently installed and last day installed setup have same date.

Comment: More information is needed, but to be honest its to broad of a question to be answered. if you could strip this down to its bare minimum and add examples then i think you would have more luck getting help.

Comment: @Peter I have added more information. hope you understand my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look into the your project setup properties that may contains same default namespace, generally that causes.

Comment: Thanks a lot got it that was the issue... Great job.